# SQL GROUP BY names using Reg ex

Tags: mysql

I am seleting data from my table and ordering by the length of a column, but I want to now group into 3 different "categories"

```
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE name LIKE 'Inclusive Minutes%' AND status = '' ORDER BY LENGTH(name);
```

the 3 different ones are like this, with multiple of each (they just have different numbers)

```
Inclusive Minutes [100 Mobile]  
Inclusive Minutes [100 National]    
Inclusive Minutes [100 National + 500 Mobile]
```

Is is possible to use a `GROUP BY` like this?

Comment: You can try using [```case```](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) stament in the ```order by```, and using ```count()``` accomplish the third rule

Comment: share more info on data and columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement to select the 3 types and group by them:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN name LIKE '%[%National%Mobile]' THEN 'National + Mobile'  
    WHEN name LIKE '%[%Mobile]' THEN 'Mobile'  
    WHEN name LIKE '%[%National]' THEN 'National'  
  END AS type,
  <aggregated columns here>
FROM prices 
WHERE name LIKE 'Inclusive Minutes%' AND status = '' 
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY LENGTH(type);
```

After the `CASE` statement you can place the aggregated columns that you want.

Comment: thanks for this, but forgive me - what do i put in the aggregated columns?

Comment: Usually we use GROUP BY to aggregate other columns like calculate sums, averages or count. So you can have something like COUNT(*) or SUM(columnname). It depends on what you you want to return by this grouping.

Comment: oh of course! i see, i tried without selecting any columns and all thats being returned is `National`

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mh5zkT6GtpMbQkEFv3bjhG/0. The code works. Is there a case that the column `status` is `null` and not `''`?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure which data you want to select, or if you are really looking to group - as `group by` will give you the aggregate values meaning one row per value. Maybe use `sum(..)` ?

But yes, `group by` works nicely with `length` , you can write `group by length(name)`.

After your comments below, seems you want to just group by the name, so this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE name LIKE 'Inclusive Minutes%' AND status = '' GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: i see what you mean with the group by length, but it could be that the numbers all different so will be different lengths

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. This groups data by name length for the 'Inclusive Minutes' entries - isn't that what you wanted? Or what result are you trying to get, please be more clear. Did you still want all individual rows? (then your original query does the job)

Comment: i just realised i didnt put my example as i thought.. so where the numbers are currently 100, they could be 1000/1500/2500 etc, so could be more than 3 digits so if i group by length, it'll split them more than i want them to. i essentially want to split by `[(0-9) (XYZ)]` where 0-9 is a string of numbers and XYZ is a string. so i want to group by the XYZ

Comment: So just group by the name itself? Or do you mean you want to ignore the numbers and group by the following string (Mobile / National) ? if you use mysql8 there is `regexp_replace()` that would work for this

Comment: yes! group by the name, so in my example it should show 3 results: `National`, `Mobile`, `National + Mobile`

Comment: Ok so just do `group by name` and done! I’ll adjust my answer. You can use `count(*), sum(..)` etc to aggregate multiple entries